# passing object with collection from domain to modelDTO with nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, dto

above is code which I use to manipulate with data from my domain to dto model, which I use for wcf serialization. My question is how to pass object mother with collection of childrens into MotherDTO. With current code situation I pass only data without collection children. Do I need to use session in line and to add session  MotherDTO dto = new MotherDTO(data, session); and to use that session to retreive collection of childrens in dto. If so, how ? Please help.

Regards,

```
public MotherDTO GetMotherData()
    {
        using (ISession session = instance.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                Mother data = session.Query<Mother>()
                    .Fetch(x => x.Childrens)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
                tx.Commit();

                MotherDTO dto = new MotherDTO(data);
                return dto;
            }
        }
    }
```

**MotherDTO.cs**

```
        public MotherDTO(Mother x)
        {
            Name = x.Name;
            List<Children>Childrens= new List<Children>();
            foreach (Children obj in x.Childrens)
            {
                States.Add(obj);
            }
        }
```

**Mother.cs**

```
 public virtual string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set
            {
                _Name = value;
            }
        }


        public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Children> Childrens
        {
            get
            {
                return _Childrens;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_Childrens == value)
                    return;
                _Childrens = value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already (eager) loading your Children collection you can use [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) to populate your DTOs.
If you want to know how to configure Automapper to work with nested collection you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789925/c-sharp-automapper-nested-collections):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.OrderLineDtos, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OrderLines));
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderLine, OrderLineDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ParentOrderDto, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ParentOrder));
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```